# Calculate a column value backwards over a series of previous rows/RECURSIVE/CONNECTED BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

need your help. I guess/hope there is a function for that. I found "CONNECT DBY" and "WITH RECURSIVE AS ..." but it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

GIVEN TABLES:

Table A

```
+------+------------+----------+
| id   |   prev_id  |  date    |
+------------------------------+
| 1    |            | 20200101 |
| 23   |     1      | 20200104 |
| 34   |     23     | 20200112 |
| 41   |     34     | 20200130 |
+------------------------------+
```

Table B

```
+------+-----------+
| ref_id  |  key   |
+------------------+
|    41   |  abc   |
+------------------+
```

(points always to the lates entry in table "A". Update, no history)

Join Statement:

SELECT
id, prev_id, key, date
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.ref_id = A.id

GIVEN psql result set:

```
+------+------------+----------+-----------+
| id   |   prev_id  |    key   |   date    |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| 1    |            |          | 20200101  |
| 23   |     1      |          | 20200104  |
| 34   |     23     |          | 20200112  |
| 41   |     34     |   abc    | 20200130  |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

DESIRED output:

```
+------+------------+----------+-----------+
| id   |   prev_id  |    key   |   date    |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| 1    |            |   abc    | 20200101  |
| 23   |     1      |   abc    | 20200104  |
| 34   |     23     |   abc    | 20200112  |
| 41   |     34     |   abc    | 20200130  |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

The rows of the result set are connected by columns 'id' and 'prev_id'.
I want to calculate the "key" column in a reasonable time.
Keep in mind, this is a very simplified example. Normally there are a lot of more rows and different keys and id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to bring the hierarchy of each row in `tableb`. Here is one approach using a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select a.id, a.prev_id, a.date, b.key
    from tablea a
    inner join tableb b on b.ref_id = a.id
    union all
    select a.id, a.prev_id, a.date, c.key
    from cte c
    inner join tablea a on a.id = c.prev_id
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for the comment. It works! But I have to admit, I am still not sure, why it works. I will have closer look into psql documentation. Maybe I will come up with a follow up question.